# High-qualilty videos for New Practical Chinese Reader

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources, chinese

[新实用汉语课本 or *New Practical Chinese Reader*](http://www.blcup.com/CW110?id=1006) is a series of textbooks for learning Standard Chinese published by  Beijing Language and Culture University Press. There are six textbooks, containing 70 lessons in total, and each textbook is accompanied by a workbook and a set of CDs with recordings of the dialogues and other audio materials for the textbook. (The adjective "new" in the title is based on the fact that this series is the successor of the older [*Practical Chinese Reader*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_Chinese_Reader). The characters Gubo and Ding Yun from the older series are the parents of Ding Libo in the new series.)

On YouTube is is quite easy to find [videos for these lessons](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22new+practical+chinese+reader%22+site%3Ayoutube.com&t=ffab&ia=web). These videos were acted by different people than those who recorded the CDs; they are also spoken faster than the CDs. (By the way, one of the actors is [Charlotte MacInnis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ai_Hua).)

The visual quality of these videos is rather low, as if they had been compressed very strongly, so I was wondering if they are available anywhere in a higher resolution (legally, obviously).